# "if" statement is not working for np.abs(np.max(f_5.all()))

Tags: python, numpy, data-manipulation

```
for ii in range (0,70):
    for jj in range (0,70):
        f_max = 0
        for k in range (0,50):
            if np.abs(np.max(f_5.all())) > f_max:
                f_max = f_5 #(+/-)
                idx=k
```

Here `f_5` shape is `(70,70,50)` and it has maximum values around 360 and minimum values around 230. I want to save the max value and that points index in `k`. But the `f_max` is not updating.

Comment: Read the docs (including examples) of "ndarray.all". What do you think should "all" do?

Comment: If I use any that provides this ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: You can use `np.abs(f_5.max())` to find max then compare it to `f_max`. If it fits you can use `idx = f_5.argmax()`.

Comment: You don't use `ii` and `jj`, and apply `all` to the array every time.  Pay close attention to what's happening in the loop.  Practice on a simpler 1d list.

Comment: Please update a more complete reproducible version of your code and a bit more explanation of what you want to achieve so we can help better. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you are looking for this without a need for loops:

```
idx_max = np.unravel_index(f_5.argmax(), f_5.shape)
idx = idx_max[2]
f_max = f_5[idx_max]
```

or equivalently a less efficient approach (since it searches for max and also searches for index separately) :

```
f_max = np.amax(f_5)
idx = np.argwhere(f_5==f_max)[0,2]
```

Comment: Don't call max and argmax twice. Argmax and index

Comment: @MadPhysicist `argmax()` returns flattened index, while OP seems to care about index along an axis. While you can use  argmax and indexing, that should not make a difference for a (70,70,50) array. Thank you for the point. I am editing accordingly.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes. but OP does NOT want the _maximum along an axis_. It is the _index along an axis of maximum_ (over all array axis). It is different than maximum along same axis. Having that said, I changed the solution to reflect your point. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Apparently I don't know how to read :)

Comment: The argwhere solution (also plain where) is really inefficient. It goes through an entire boolean mask the size of the array after the pass required to find the max. No harm in presenting it, but it's not a clean approach.

Comment: Also, `f_max = f_5[idx_max]` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I agree with you that the second approach is not efficient. Just put it there since it is easier to read/understand. Adding a note to reflect your point. Thank you for noting the typo as well. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the coordinates of your max value:

```
f_5_max = np.amax(f_5)
max_coord = np.hstack(np.where(f_5 == f_5_max))
```

Comment: Use argmax instead